# Macro Google Sheet Copy and Paste on Every day

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, paste

needs help regarding the macro
I currently have such a code

```js
function getDynamicRows(){

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('B.Wioski');
var sourceRange = sheet.getRange('A1:F26500');
var data = sourceRange.getValues(); // Array of arrays [[Row1],[Row1],[Row3]]

// add data to next empty row in the static sheet.
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('TW');
data.forEach(function(row){
targetSheet.appendRow(row)
}) ;
}
```

but the google sheet has a problem because the macro works max 6 min and it reads a maximum of 400 lines
and I would need a Macro that would copy A1 cells to F26500 where it would perform this activity 4 times a day every 6h for a maximum of 7 days and then on the 8th day it would delete the first day or overwrite the cells again

Comment: When I proposed an answer for using `setValues`, you said `I have already done`. unfortunately, I couldn't notice it from your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. In this case, I think that my answer was not useful for your question. So I have to delete my answer. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: she was very useful you helped me a lot

Comment: I have one more request to replace "row" with "col"

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can I ask you about the detail of your question? For example, your 1st question has already been resolved and you want to change your initial question. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: now the macro backs up correctly every 6 hours
but I need to replace the macro to write the data in the columns and not in the rows as before

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that your 1st question has already been resolved and you want to change your initial question. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `now the macro backs up correctly every 6 hours but I need to replace the macro to write the data in the columns and not in the rows as before`. Can I ask you about the detail of your new question?

Comment: now it looks like this
A1:F26500
next makro
A26501:F53000 
ect. ect.
and I do 
A1:F26500
next
G1:L26500
Ect. Ect.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detail of `A1:F26500 next makro A26501:F53000 ect. ect. and I do A1:F26500 next G1:L26500`? For example, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect as the image?

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/9W95KkQ/Bez-tytu-u.png

Comment: Thank you for providing the sample images. From your sample images, I thought that I might be able to understand your question. So I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: sorry i didn't see this post do you have a macro that would delete data after 5 days?

Comment: From `sorry i didn't see this post`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation and your question. So I would like to delere my answer again. This is due to my poor English skill. I apologize for this again. I think that I have to study English more and more.

Comment: I have modified the macro
now places one column (this is the most important)
from:
var sourceRange = sheet.getRange('A1:F26500');
to:
var sourceRange = sheet.getRange('F1:F26500');

and needs it after 5 days
so that the "G" cell would be overwritten again

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `appendRow()` use `setValues()`.

If you keep exceeding the 6 mins, you can create multiple triggers (Row 1-5000, 5001-1000...) or copy the entire sheet and set formulas in your 'TW' sheet making reference to the copied sheets.